# Clash of multivalued attribute

Tags: sql

I am having a database having name and hobbies(as multivalued attribute) and  I want to find out what is the count of occurence of more than one same value
For example
If this is a sample database

```
A reading
A dancing
B reading
B dancing
```

Then the result should be

```
List of hobbies  | Number of occurrence
-----------------|---------------------
reading, dancing | 2
```

Comment: And if the number of occurrences is different for each hobby?

Comment: Each hobby can have different occurence but my question is how many persons has both reading and dancing as their hobbies

Comment: Are all of these on one table?

Comment: And your DB engine is?

Comment: Yes they are all on the same table

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a query like this:

```
SELECT hobbies, Count(*) As hNo 
FROM t
GROUP BY hobbies
```

That have a result set like this:

```
hobbies | hNo
--------+------
reading | 2 
dancing | 2
```

Now for this data-set you can follow answers of this question [[Concatenate many rows into a single text string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/4519059)] to have them in one row.